# How to do calculation in python?

Tags: python, pandas

My Dataframe consists Columns 'Confirmed', 'Death', and 'Recovered'. I need to add new Columns 'Death Rate %' and 'Recover Rate %'.

The formula is calculated as below:

```
Death Rate % =  Death / Confirmed × 100
```

and

```
Recovery Rate % = Recovered / Confirmed × 100
```

I don't have any ideas on this. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code writing service. Please show your efforts

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have a Dataframe called df.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Confirmed': [100, 200, 300],
                     'Death': [10, 40, 90], 
                     'Recovered': [45, 60, 50]})

# this code will add the columns 'Death Rate' and 'Recovery Rate'

df['Death Rate'] = df['Death'] / df['Confirmed'] * 100
df['Recovery Rate'] = df['Recovered'] / df['Confirmed'] * 100
```

Comment: Answered at the same second. Removed mine =)

Comment: Sorry about that, thank you though! =)

Answer (score 0):

```py
df['Death Rate'] = (df['Death'] / df['Confirmed']) * 100
df['Recovery Rate'] =  (df['Recovered'] / df['Confirmed']) * 100
```

Comment: You definitely don't need apply here

Comment: You mean multyplying columns? Something like `df['Death Rate'] = df['Death'] / df['Confirmed']) * 100` ? I confess I did not use that, I do not know its behaviour and I thought `apply` is safer :))

Comment: Apply is by no means safer (nor unsafe?), it's just way slower

Comment: Indeed, myself I prefer to use applymap when there is no other possibility.

Comment: Sorry, wrote the same thing as @Vittorio.